# ResultSet Meta data return TimeStamp instead of Date Oracle JDBC

Tags: java, oracle, date, jdbc, timestamp

I Have a Table `WRITE_DATE_DATA` having column `DATE_DATA` (`DATE` type) and `TIMESTAMP_DATA` (`TIMESTAMP(6)` Type).

When I am executing:

```
ResultSet rsmeta = ps.executeQuery("Select DATE_DATA,TIMESTAMP_DATA from WRITE_DATE_DATA")
ResultSetMetaData rsmeta = resultSet.getMetaData()  ;
int imax = rsmeta.getColumnCount() ;
HashMap<String, Integer> hmRsColTypes = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for ( int ii = 0 ; ii < imax ; ii++ )
{
  String strColumn = rsmeta.getColumnName(ii+1);
  System.out.println(rsmeta.getColumnType(ii+1));// line 1
  System.out.println(rsmeta.getColumnType(ii+1));// line 2
}
```

> Output:
>
> at line 1 - TIMESTAMP_DATA
>
> at line 2 -93 Type for java.sql.TimeStamp
>
> at line 1 -     DATE_DATA
>
> at line one - 93 Type for java.sql.TimeStamp
>
> Expected data type for DATE_DATE will be 91 Type for java.sql.Date

Why is `ResultSetMetaData` returning the wrong data type `TimeStamp` instead of `Date` data type?

Is this expected behavior, if yes then please share document or should i do something else to handle it.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That question was answered for diffrence between Date and TIMESTAMP,,I am not asking difference , I am getting wrong data type of column in ResultSetMetaData. Is this expected behavior or should i do something else

Answer (score 3):

The output shown is correct. An Oracle `DATE` is a `java.sql.Timestamp` (`java.sql.Types.TIMESTAMP`) as far as JDBC (and the SQL standard) is concerned as it has both a date and time component.

An Oracle `DATE` is simply not a date as defined in JDBC and the SQL standard. Use of `java.sql.Date` (and `java.sql.Types.DATE`) is for types that have only a date component (day, month, year).

See also: [Difference between oracle DATE and TIMESTAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141030/difference-between-oracle-date-and-timestamp?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: If both are behaving same then what's the need of Date type itself. Is there any Oracle official document, which elaborate this issue.

Comment: @Afgan The oracle `DATE` type predates the SQL standard, other databases from that era have the same 'problem' (eg Firebird in the deprecated dialect 1, date is also a timestamp), Oracle **later** introduced `TIMESTAMP`, which provides sub-second precision options with closer alignment to the SQL standard. And, re _"Is there any Oracle official document, which elaborate this issue."_ probably, but you should search for that yourself, SO is not a 'mechanical turk'-search engine.