# Date vs Timestamp vs Interval (Second to Day, etc.) on the basis of performance, efficiency and superiority in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Date and Timestamps both have time added and interval is used in case of manipulation of dates via addition yearwise, datewise etc.

Still unsure about the exact actual difference though when it comes to dates in oracle especially.

Is there any major difference in terms of efficiency or some other difference on the usage of date, timestamp and interval?

Comment: So what's the question ?

Comment: duplicate as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19141030/difference-between-oracle-date-and-timestamp

Comment: @Barbaros like we have options via To_char() to manipulate data that includes dates as well. But, this is inefficient as it is conversion overhead added. In terms of efficiency how would you use date, timestamp or interval even when theres nothing related to precision difference as such but manipulation may require atmost. Also, if its just that timestamp has more precised value than date then why there is seperate timestamp type just for precision of time when date contains all the info and is of same 7 bytes size

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja they are not both the same size. A `TIMESTAMP` takes 11 bytes and a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` takes 13. `DATE` values can't have a time zone. Does that answer your question?

Comment: As you said timezone is the difference between date and timestamp when added but are you sure I mean just that for referring timezone we should use timestamp type and date regardless of having time info, year, century etc becomes of no use when timezone with date is required. Also what if no timezone is required but we need precised date with time precision and performance wize what should I use then date or timestamp. Without timezone its again of 7 bytes

Comment: If you ask for efficiency: Are you concerned about a difference of 4 Bytes?

Comment: Yeah upto some extent but I wanna know when we have everything in date except timezone then why there is a seperate timestamp type. I mean suppose timezone isnt required then should I go for date or timestamp for efficiency then itll be date right

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja *"timezone is the difference between date and timestamp when added"* - not quite, the differences are timezone and fractional seconds. `DATE` only stores whole seconds. How are you checking the sizes? I used the `dump()` function on a timestamp column in 12.2 and the output begins `Typ=180 Len=11`. Not 7.

Comment: Umm... unsure about what to say regarding this thatll add more confusion. It somewhat clears out that date is superior to timestamp but just that their usage differs on the requirement compensating efficiency sometimes. Suppose data with timezone sometimes is the feed to a particular column but the count is very less as compared to data without timezone. So, this would be less efficient with timestamp and there wouldnt be any other option like to have date type. I hope that clears about my actual query

Comment: You should **never** manipulate date or timestamp values via `TO_CHAR()`. If you have to manipulate those values then run them directly on DATE or TIMESTAMP data.

Comment: Hmm true @Wernfried Domscheit. Thanks man for helping out that all in all helps me understand better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear but this information may help you.

- `TIMESTAMP` supports fractional seconds, unlike `DATE` which supports only seconds
- TIMESTAMP exist in three flavors:

  - `TIMESTAMP` does not contain any time zone information.
  - `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE` contain time zone information
- Regarding calculation and manipulation there is actually no difference between `TIMESTAMP` and `DATE`. There are only a very few functions which support only either of these two types.
- `DATE` is an old data type. `TIMESTAMP` was introduced later (well "later" means in 9i, i.e. 20 years ago)
  `INTERVAL YEAR TO MONTH` and `INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND` are interval data types, they do not contain any absolute date information.

Hope this gave some hints. Otherwise please elaborate your question.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for your valuable efforts.

Answer (score -2):

date does not store fractional seconds so comparing time with date less than  1 sec wont work!!!!!